# Save a record in android application after it has been randomly selected from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an Android activity which has a database. Every day when user starts the app and clicked "Today's word", the app will randomly choose a word from database and show its data on a new activity. I know if user restarts the app/ closes the app, the selected word will be changed again. How to deal with this problem? And how to prevent the app from choosing the same word after the day has passed?

Thank you

Comment: Just add a column for "seen" (boolean), TRUE means seen already, FALSE haven't seen yet. Then select those record with FALSE seen flag and finally do your random logic.

Comment: Because of the app save/restore cycle you can't rely on local or member variables to be maintained when your application isn't in the current active application, so just saving the state in a variable will not work.  See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the last time a word was displayed, and the word itself by implementing your activity's `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods.  Then when your app is restored you can check the timestamp to see if a new word should be displayed. `onSaveInstanceState` will be called when another application is activated and yours is deactivated, or when the OS decides that it can safely idle your application. `onRestoreInstanceState` will be called when the user attempts to activate your application again.

See the following android dev links for details:

- [Overview](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)
- [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))
- [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))